# Map scale on Gmap.net

Tags: c#, maps, gmap.net

How to get the map scale on Gmap.net?
I need the scale to calculate the dimensions of an image in relation to the map dimension.
Is it possible to obtain this data on Gmap.net?

Comment: If you use SVG format, it has layers.  So the map image is one layer and other layer contain the street name and other location info.  The scale can also be in one of the layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem when I went to add custom marker to GMap(scaling width, height, pen size, ...). You can use below code to get GMap.Net Overlayer scale value.

```
double scale = Overlay.Control.MapProvider.Projection.GetGroundResolution((int)Overlay.Control.Zoom, Position.Lat));
```

And use below to scaling your dimensions.

```
var h = Height/scale;
var w = Width/scale;
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10/scale);
```

I hope this help